# How to create a user permission matrix report by using powershell/sharegate powershell script for sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

Kindly provide information on, how to create a user permission matrix report by using powershell/sharegate powershell script for SharePoint Online?

Comment: I don't see any help on SharePoint online, all are available for on premises SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Full disculosure, I work for Sharegate. Unfortunately this isn't possible at the moment, but feel free to vote for the feature on Sharegate's Uservoice here: https://sharegate.uservoice.com/forums/373710-sharegate-desktop/suggestions/19337017-use-management-actions-and-features-in-powershell

Good luck!